# Stored Function with Multiple Queries and Different Selected Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have series of queries based on a report type.  For simplicity here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
If @Reporttype = '1'
Select lcustomerid, lname, fname
from customers
Where dtcreated > @startdate

Else if @Reporttype = '2'
Select barcode, lname, fname 
from employees
where dtcreated > @startdate

Else if @reporttype = '3'
Select thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid
from Customers
where dtcreated > @startdate
```

You'll notice that I run 3 separate queries, based on the report type being passed.  You'll also notice I am returning different columns and the number of columns.

I'd like to make this a stored function, and return the columns I need based on the report type I pass.  However, I know that since the number of columns, and the column names are different - that's not going to work as a stored function as I'd like it to.

The major problem here will be reporting this information - I don't want to have separate functions, because i'll have to maintain different reports for each report type.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: Not as a user defined function, but you can create a stored procedure out of it with no problem at all.

Comment: Try This `Create proc Proc_name (@Reporttype char(1))
as
begin
If @Reporttype = '1'
Select lcustomerid, lname, fname
from customers
Where dtcreated > @startdate

Else if @Reporttype = '2'
Select barcode, lname, fname 
from employees
where dtcreated > @startdate

Else if @reporttype = '3'
Select thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid
from Customers
where dtcreated > @startdate
end`

Comment: I think you should have 3 different functions or store procs and control which one to execute from your code coz you will need different way to handle data returned based on the reporttype.

Comment: Stored function?  Do you mean stored procedure or function?

Comment: If this is for a reporting system, I think I would suggest that you use a stored function and return an XML data type.  However, the use of XML might require further changes to your application.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is interesting - Could you give me a little more information on this?

Comment: What is your end destination of the data? Are  you using a packaged reporting tool where the returned columns must be the same every time or a custom reporting tool/app that can handle varied columns?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using a stored procedure? It seems the most suitable method according to your needs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multi-statement function but you need to specify all columns which will be returned by 3 select statements. It seems it's impossible return multiple result sets.

> User-defined functions can not return multiple result sets. Use a
>   stored procedure if you need to return multiple result sets. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx

This is one inconvenience but in report you can use only columns you need, others will be nulls.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFun
(
    @Reporttype int,
    @startdate datetime
)
RETURNS 
@Result TABLE 
(
    lcustomerid int, 
    lname nvarchar(50),
    fname nvarchar(50),
    barcode int,
    thetime datetime,
    name nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    If @Reporttype = '1'
        insert into @Result (lcustomerid, lname, fname)
        select lcustomerid, lname, fname
        from customers
        Where dtcreated > @startdate

    Else if @Reporttype = '2'
        insert into @Result (barcode, lname, fname)
        Select barcode, lname, fname 
        from employees
        where dtcreated > @startdate

    Else if @reporttype = '3'
        insert into @Result (thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid)
        Select thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid
        from customers
        where dtcreated > @startdate

    RETURN 
END
```

So, you can call function in this way

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFun (1, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it is difficult to create something similar so generic or abstract, especially when it has to do with SELECT of colums. If your purpose is to write as less code as you can in order your sql script to be maintained easily and to be able to add new report types in the future with just minor changes I would suggest to use a stored procedure with dynamic sql. You cannot use a function while you wisk your SELECT to be dynamic, its the wrong method. I would write something like that

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
(
@ReportType int,
@startdate datetime
)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @colNames varchar(MAX),@tblName varchar(MAX),@sSQL varchar(MAX);
SELECT @colNames = CASE 
                    WHEN @ReportType = 1 THEN
                     'lcustomerid, lname, fname' --You can also add alias
                     WHEN @ReportType = 2 THEN
                     'barcode, lname, fname'
                     WHEN @ReportType = 3 THEN
                     'thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid'
                     ELSE
                     RAISEERROR('Error msg');
                    END,
        @tblName = CASE 
                    WHEN @ReportType = 1 OR @ReportType = 3 THEN
                     'customers' --You can also add alias
                    WHEN @ReportType = 2 THEN
                     'employees'
                     ELSE
                     RAISEERROR('Error msg');
                    END

SET @sSQL = 
'Select '+@colNames+'
from '+@tblName +'
where dtcreated > '''+CONVERT(varchar(10), @startdate, 121)+''''

EXEC(@sSQL)
END
```

And you will call it as

```
EXEC MyProcedure 1,'20170131'
```

for example
With this code every time you want a new report type you will need to add just another line in case with the requested column names. I have used this way in working with Crystal reports and I think it is the best possible solution

Comment: There may be some syntax errors, I have not tested but you can see my point

Comment: Your query works only with one table, but should works also with employees table. And in question comment a SP is offered already without dynamic query.

Comment: Your are right, I hadn't seen that table name changes, I edited the answer. Indeed the SP can work without dynamic sql but in this case the SELECT statement should be re-written. My purpose was to create a script with as few code repetitions as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use stored procedure and you need to use a function, you can `UNPIVOT` the data and than in the `client side` you can `PIVOT` it.

I need to do something like this when different number of columns are returned to `SQL Server Reporting Services` report. For example, the following code is always returning three columns - `RowID`, `Column`, `Value`:

```
DECLARE @Table01 TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Value01] INT
   ,[Value02] NVARCHAR(256)
   ,[Value03] SMALLINT
);

DECLARE @Table02 TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Value01] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table01 ([ID], [Value01], [Value02], [Value03])
VALUES (1, 111, '1V2', 7)
      ,(2, 222, '2V2', 8)
      ,(3, 333, '3V2', 9);

INSERT INTO @Table02 ([ID], [Value01])
VALUES (1, 111)
      ,(2, 222)
      ,(3, 333);


-- your function starts here

DECLARE @Mode SYSNAME = 'Table01' -- try with 'Table02', too

DECLARE @ResultSet TABLE
(
    [RowID] INT
   ,[Column] SYSNAME
   ,[Value] NVARCHAR(128)
);

IF @Mode = 'Table01'
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO @ResultSet ([RowID], [Column], [Value])
        SELECT [ID]
              ,[Column]
              ,[Value]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT [ID]
                  ,CAST([Value01] AS NVARCHAR(256))
                  ,CAST([Value02] AS NVARCHAR(256))
                  ,CAST([Value03] AS NVARCHAR(256))
            FROM @Table01
        ) DS ([ID], [Value01], [Value02], [Value03])
        UNPIVOT
        (
            [Value] FOR [Column] IN ([Value01], [Value02], [Value03])
        ) UNPVT
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO @ResultSet ([RowID], [Column], [Value])
        SELECT [ID]
              ,[Column]
              ,[Value]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT [ID]
                  ,CAST([Value01] AS NVARCHAR(256))
            FROM @Table02
        ) DS ([ID], [Value01])
        UNPIVOT
        (
            [Value] FOR [Column] IN ([Value01])
        ) UNPVT
    END;

SELECT *
FROM @ResultSet;
```

Then in the reporting I need to perform `pivot` operation again. This is workaround with many limitations:

- the `unpivot` data must be cast to its largest type (usually, string)
- unnecessary operations are performed (`pivot` -> `unpivot`) instead of just rendering the data;
- it does not working well with large amount of data (it is slow)

and others..

Answer (score 0):

For This you may create a scalar value function that return an xml type column and then you can populate that xml tag values to your report screen

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReportFunc
(
    @intReporttype int,
    @dtStartdate datetime
)
RETURNS XML
BEGIN

Declare @xmlResult xml 

    If @intReporttype = '1'
        SET @xmlResult = (
                select lcustomerid, lname, fname
                from customers
                Where dtcreated > @dtStartdate
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE  
                )

    Else if @intReporttype = '2'
        SET @xmlResult = (
                    Select barcode, lname, fname 
                    from employees
                    where dtcreated > @dtStartdate
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE  
                    )

    Else if @intReporttype = '3'
        SET @xmlResult = (  
                    Select thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid
                    from customers
                    where dtcreated > @dtStartdate
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE  
                    )

    RETURN @xmlResult
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Stored Procedures then for maintainability I would look at using a master stored procedure which calls other stored procedures to return different result sets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc_1(@startdate DateTime)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT lcustomerid, lname, fname 
    FROM customers WHERE dtcreated > @startdate 

END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc_2(@startdate DateTime)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT barcode, lname, fname 
    FROM employees where dtcreated > @startdate 
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc_3(@startdate DateTime)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid 
    FROM Customers WHERE dtcreated > @startdate
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(@Reporttype char(1), @startdate DateTime)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @Reporttype = '1' EXEC MyProc_1 @startdate
    ELSE IF @Reporttype = '2'  EXEC MyProc_2 @startdate
    ELSE IF @reporttype = '3'  EXEC MyProc_3 @startdate
END
GO
```

And to use:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime = getdate()
EXEC MyProc 1, @dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE Proc Emp_det 
(
@Reporttype INT,
@startdate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    If @Reporttype = '1' BEGIN

        Select lcustomerid, lname, fname
        FROM customers
        WHERE dtcreated > @startdate

    END 
    ELSE IF @Reporttype = '2' BEGIN

        Select barcode, lname, fname 
        FROM employees
        WHERE dtcreated > @startdate
    END
    ELSE IF @reporttype = '3' BEGIN
        Select thetime, lname, name, barcode, lcustomerid
        FROM Customers
        WHERE dtcreated > @startdate    

    END
END
GO

Exec Emp_det 1,GETDATE()
```